# Adding a Scroll-down Feature to Select Box Options using only CSS and HTML

Tags: html, css

There are enough options within the select menu that is too large to fit all the on the page. How can I make the scroll down menu within the select box so it scrolls when it runs out of space?

```
<form>
     <ul>
        <li id="snow_filter">
           <label>Enter Resort</label> <br>
           <input class="snow_scroll" id="resort" type="text" list="resortname">
           <datalist id="resortname">
              <option value="Resort1">
              <option value="Resort2">
              <option value="Resort3"> 
              <option value="Resort4">     
              ...
              <option value="Resort66">  
            </datalist>
```

I am using a form with a submit button (not shown). I am mostly familiar with HTML and CSS, so I would appreciate a solution using those languages.

Comment: The styling of `<datalist>` is vendor- and OS-specific such that there's very limited things what CSS can do.

Comment: Can you add screenshot of problem and how it should looks? `datalist` in default never shows so many items.

Answer (score 1):

```
if you want only to use html and css use this to wrap all the options in <select></select> like this:
```

```
  <select>
        <datalist id="resortname">
              <option value="Resort1">
              <option value="Resort2">
              <option value="Resort3"> 
              <option value="Resort4">     
              <option value="Resort66">  
        </datalist> 
   </select>
```